# Reuse last facebook login session after reopening application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform, facebook-login

I want to re-login a Facebook user in parse without showing login dialog of Facebook using saved TOKEN in Parse.

I am using 3 methods for save and restore session but how to use them in Facebook object of `ParseFacebookUtils`?

```
/*
 * Save the access token and expiry date so you don't have to fetch it each
 * time
 */
public static boolean save(Facebook session, Context context) {
    Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString(TOKEN, session.getAccessToken());
    editor.putLong(EXPIRES, session.getAccessExpires());
    editor.putLong(LAST_UPDATE, session.getLastAccessUpdate());
    return editor.commit();
}

/*
 * Restore the access token and the expiry date from the shared preferences.
 */
public static boolean restore(Facebook session, Context context) {
    SharedPreferences savedSession = context.getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    session.setTokenFromCache(
            savedSession.getString(TOKEN, null),
            savedSession.getLong(EXPIRES, 0),
            savedSession.getLong(LAST_UPDATE, 0));
    return session.isSessionValid();
}

public static void clear(Context context) {
    Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}
```

And i am restoring session by following before login-

```
    ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(APP_ID);
    // restore session
    restore(ParseFacebookUtils.getFacebook(), this);
    // login using restored data
    ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(permissions, LoginActivity.this,
            new LogInCallback() {
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {

                // work after login

                        ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
                        save(ParseFacebookUtils.getFacebook(),this);
                }});
```

But it's not working it always opens login dialog of facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by calling openActiveSession method with allowLoginUI = false in onCreate() method of my Activity.
My code is-

```
ParseFacebookUtils.getSession().openActiveSession(this, false, new Session.StatusCallback() {

@Override
public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
{
     if (session.isOpened()) {

        ParseFacebookUtils.logIn( LoginActivity.this,
                        new LogInCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                            // user logged in
                            }

                    });
              }
              else 
              {
                // error found
              }
           }
        });
```